# Why doesn't for...in print out properties from Object?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototypal-inheritance

I wrote the following javascript and expected to see all the properties from Obj2 listed along with properties from (what I thought) would be the base class - Object.  Why do I not see properties like prototype and toString listed along with one and two?

```
Obj2 = function() {
   this.one = "one";
   this.two = "two";
}

var obj2 = new Obj2();

for(var i in obj2) {
    try {
        console.log(i + ": " + obj2[i]);
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(i + " caused error: " + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for...in` only iterates over enumerable properties. `toString` and `prototype` are not enumerable properties. Have a read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in . The description in that link literally explains why `toString` and `prototype` are not enumerated, and uses them specifically as examples

Comment: If you want to iterate over methods up the prototype chain, take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties . There are several methods at the bottom that you can look through to accomplish what you want

Comment: FYI, only functions have a `prototype` property. `obj2` is not a function.

Comment: Well, Ian's comment answers your question. But why are you using try/catch there? I can't see a scenario where logging i and obj2[i] would throw an error.

Comment: @bfavaretto I sometimes experienced an error when iterating over the properties of for instance the window object. I got the key `i` but as soon as I tried to access `window[i]`, for some properties, it threw an error. So far, this only happend in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lan said `for ... in` iterates only on enumerable properties, and if you want to get all properties of instance (enumerable or not) you can try
[Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/qv4Qt/2/)

```
function Obj2() {
    this.one = "one";
    this.two = "two";
}

var obj2 = new Obj2(),
    proto = obj2,
    keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto);


while (proto) {
    for (var i in keys) {
        try {
            console.log(keys[i] + ": " + proto[keys[i]]);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(i + " caused error: " + e);
        }
    }
    proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);
    keys = proto ? Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto) : null;
}
```